# Trying to find a specific story about a sound

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Several years ago, probably around 2010/2011, I think I was using stumbleupon that I came across a website with a short story, I've been trying hard to find it again but I still haven't found, hopefully somebody here can help.

The story goes something like:

Suddenly, all around the world a sound started, everyone could hear it and it was so loud it was almost impossible to verbally communicate. The sound didn't stop, it drove some people crazy but eventually people got used to the sound, babies were born into it and knew nothing better and people became accustomed to lip reading and sign language. It carried on this way until one day the sound stopped, and that drove everyone crazy again.

I know that's not much to go on but that's as much as I can remember. The website I feel had minimalistic look with blacks and whites, no colour, and the story I think was in a thin'ish column in the middle.

Hopefully there is someone out there who knows this.

Comment: 2010 was quite a few years ago? I must be getting old.

Comment: @amaranth I know what you mean, but it *was* the better part of a decade ago, now.  Personally, I still get tripped up when people start talking about the 90s like it's ancient history.

Comment: I remember reading a story in the 80s about a world where nearly everyone was deaf because of a war using sound weapons, could it be that?

Comment: @amaranth：I guess I should of put several years。@DanielRoseman： that sounds interesting but the story I read was deffinatly a sound，not deaf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you referring to "The Most Annoying Sound in the World?" I honestly haven't read this before you posted your question, but I got really curious of the story you're looking for so I searched for it and I found [this on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/35giov/tomt_story_short_story_with_a_loud_sound_that/).

EDIT:
[Here](http://www.burningbuilding.com/mystery/noise.htm) is the actual link to the story. I think this is the story you're looking for because it matches your description.

Comment: YES!!! Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't find that link on reddit...

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. You're welcome.